# Are the dopri5 or dop853 integrator methods in Scipy.integrate.ode re-entrant?

Tags: python, multithreading, numerical-methods, ode

Basically I am trying to construct a multithreaded integrator using the Runge-Kutta numerical integrators in Scipy's library.  I know the other integration methods such as lsoda, zvode and vode are all non re-entrant and cannot be threaded, but is that true for dopri5 and dop853 as well?  The documentation center does not specify.